# JAVA creating an event list from a text file

Tags: java, file, class, events, constructor

I have a controller class, it basically holds an event list.

```
ArrayList <Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The controller has an addEvent(Event e) method.

I've extended the controller class to be a specific kind of controller, and extended event to provide specific kinds of events for my new controller as inner classes.

```
public class NewController extends Controller{
    //.. controller code/methods
    class SpecificEvent extends Event{
        //..
    } 
}
```

I've hard coded my controller to work as I intended, but I wanted to be able to make a configuration file that would populate my event list.

I made a .txt file with a list of events:

```
Event=SpecificEvent, Arg1=<Integer>val, .. ArgN=<?>val, Event=SpecificEventN, ArgN=<?>val
```

I filtered out the event class name and arguments into a list:

```
fileContents.stream()
      .forEach(s -> {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(s)
             .useDelimiter("=|,");
         while (sc.hasNext()){
             Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(sc.next()).useDelimiter("[//w]");
             args.add(sc.next());
         }
   });
```

My problem is that events have different constructor argument types and lengths; I don't know how to build them from my file. I'm new to this kind of work and I figure this is run of the mill implementation.

Do I use the Reflect package? Please help. I was thinking off an Event Factory?

Comment: Yes, you need to use reflection.  Start by looking at all of the methods of [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: Why is ordinary serialization not an option?

Comment: @VGR Unfortunately not the answer I was hoping for. This means I'll most likely need to build some kind of switch statement based of the event type string within my event factory. Thanks!

Comment: @Fildor I never said it wasn't. I'm new to this. I will look into serialization, but I thought I would need to create the .txt file based off of the output of a serialized event and not the requested format I've posted.

Comment: Do you want that config to be human-readable and editable outside of your application? Then you may want to also look for JAXB or something in that direction.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, I'll also look into JAXB, as yes, it must be human readable as like the posted .txt file format.

Comment: @iinertiaii A switch statement should not be necessary.  Either use Class.forName or keep a `Map<String, Class<? extends Event>>` in a field.

Comment: @VGR Thanks. I will update my progress on this side project with time permitting.

Comment: I had this on the back burner and got back too it. I updated my regex too : "([\\w]*)?=|(\n|\r)" and used reflection to build my events. for those who try this method, make sure the class path is properly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the community help. This factory will do the job when provided a string array argument, `{String classname, args.... }`

`/**
     * ClassFactory  method, build an event.
     *
     * @param arguments Required arguments to build an Event.
     * @return Built event.
     * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     */`

```
public Event buildEvent(String [] arguments) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?>[] argumentTypes = {};
    Object[] parameters = {};

    try {
        //define the class type from the first argument    
        Class<?> eventClass
                = Class.forName(packageName + arguments[0]);   
        if (arguments.length() > 1) {
            argumentTypes = new Class<?>[]{Long.TYPE};
            parameters = new Object[]{Long.parseLong(arguments[1])};

            Constructor<?> constructor
                    = eventClass.getDeclaredConstructor(argumentTypes);
            Object instance = constructor.newInstance(parameters);
            return ((Event) instance);
        //default 
        } else {
            Constructor<?> constructor
                    = eventClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
            Object instance = constructor.newInstance();
            return ((Event) instance);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println("Class not available in this package.");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException |
            SecurityException |
            InstantiationException |
            IllegalAccessException |
            IllegalArgumentException |
            InvocationTargetException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Class Builder: {0}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```